# PHP show more system

Tags: php

I have got this HTML

```
 <div class="V_CPp">
  <span class="ViewC">View more comments</span>
 </div>
<div class="hov_c">
   <div class="CommentsAwp Comment_Hs CA">
                        <img src="../users/<?php echo $CommenterPicture[0];?>">
                        <span><?php echo $CommenterName[0]; ?></span>
                        <span class="s2"><?php echo $CommentRow[1]; ?></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

And this Jquery/AJAX

```
$(".V_CPp").click(function(event) {
    var numItems = $(this).siblings('.F_W_comments').children().children().length;
    var i=$(this).siblings(".c_jq").children(".Likes").attr("data-i");
    $.ajax({
        url: '../connect.php',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:"VMC="+i+"&NI="+numItems,                         
        success: function(data)
        {
             $("body").html(data);   
        }    
    });
});
```

And this php(connect.php)

```
if (isset($_GET['VMC'])) {
    $RandS=$_GET['VMC'];
    $From=$_GET['NI'];
    $To=$From+4;
    $query=$con->query("SELECT id FROM uploads WHERE Rand='$RandS'");
    $Id=$query->fetch_row();
    $Commentsq=$con->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Post_id='$Id[0]' ORDER BY `DATE` DESC LIMIT $From,$To) AS sub ORDER BY `DATE` ASC");
    while($COMM=$Commentsq->fetch_row())
    {   
        echo $COMM[1]."<br />";
    }
}
```

So  when i have lets say 13 comments in order from 1 to 13
It only shows 10-13 and when i click

```
<div class="V_CPp">
```

It shows me all comments from 2 to 9 instead of 6-9

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
                        <span class="s2"><?php echo $CommentRow[0]; ?></span>
```

instead

```
                        <span class="s2"><?php echo $CommentRow[1]; ?></span>
```

Try and comment please, maybe this is the issue.

Best of lucks,

Comment: It will return me Id of comment not the text

Comment: And     $To=$From+1; instead of     $To=$From+4; ?